# Chipsets that provides access to baseband bits

Tags: usb, ethernet, usb-device, pcie

Are there any chipsets for high-speed wired connections like USB3.0, Ethernet or PCIe that provides access to the raw signals being transmitted and received along the wire? Kind of like how a software radio provides access to the raw I/Q samples.

Comment: What do you mean, "baseband bits", in USB case for example?

Comment: Access to the raw signal being transmitted and received. Kind of like a software radio gives you access to the raw I/Q samples

Comment: If you want the raw signals, then look at the raw signals.  What good will the chip do you?   But keep in mind that these are often going to be too fast to process by conventional means.  You might also look at the role of the "Phy" rather than the interface engine in a two-part design.  Perhaps what you want is a phy as a front end to your custom processing logic?

Comment: Deleted my answer as Chris pointed out I missed the answer. Sounds like you're looking for some kind of high-speed DSA from Tektronix?

Comment: I'm struck by the fact that all the interfaces mentioned in the OP are (roughly speaking) differential signaling serial interfaces interfaces. Are you wanting the differential signaling as a bit stream based on some sampling / timing parameters? There's nothing 'generic' that does that afaik, but it sounds like a sweet spot for an FPGA.

Comment: Hook up the wire to your favourite SDR instead of an antenna. (You might need some impedance matching network as well)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of chipsets is to interface user data into a channel. User data are encoded (8b/10b, 128b/132b, scrambled, wrapped with sync, PID, and EOP patterns, supplied with CRC), then transmitted into physical media, with various enhancing tricks. The purpose of chipsets is exactly to offload all this stuff from real user data, so no such thing exists as you are asking for.

To get the "baseband data", there are fast oscilloscopes (for USB 3.0 you need a 8 - 12 GHz scope) that can capture the channel data, and then post-process them (linearly equalized, got frequency lock, then symbol lock), and can give you raw data. This process is limited by scope memory, so you can't capture much.

To access longer data, a special class of instruments exists called "protocol analyzers", who take the raw data and pre-process them (actually using the same PHY that is used in real communication channel), and raw decoded bytes can be logged.